# Проблема с авторизацией на сайте....Помогите

Tags: php

Вот код авторизации

prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?");
        $r->execute(array($email, $pass));
        if($r->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            $q = $r->fetch();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $q['Id'];
            echo success('**Вы успешно авторизовались! Перенаправление в аккаунт**');
            Header("Location: /?a=account");
            //exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo error('**Не правильные данные**');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo error('**Не тот формат E-Mail**');
    }
}
?>

#### ВХОД В АККАУНТ

**Еще не зарегистрированы?**  [**Зарегистрируйтесь!**](/?a=signup)

Авторизация

 АВТОРИЗОВАТЬСЯ

**Забыли пароль?** [**Востановление пароля**](/?a=respass)

Вопрос в том что после авторизации скрипт не переходит в аккаунт тоесть нет входа в сессию  под id пользователя ....и тем самым авторизации нет а лишь появляеться  строка  ( Вы успешно авторизовались! Перенаправление в аккаунт )